# getting error while using ng style in angular

Tags: angular

componet.ts
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/DnAeX.png)

componet.thml[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/cmGcX.png)

I am using ng-style mean while I am getting error like .
Error: src/app/app.component.ts:30:10 - error TS7006: Parameter 'Country' implicitly has an 'any' type.

30 getcolor(Country){
~~~~~~~
*your text*[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/D2z4v.png)
what to do?

Comment: Please do not add screenshots of your code to the question! *Write* the code to the question

Answer (score 0):

Country isn’t typed.  Use `getColor(Country: any)` or `getColor(Country: string)`